# How to prevent logo scaling for secondary tiles?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, secondary-live-tile

I'm creating a secondary tile and the only logo I have is quite small (32x32 pixels I think).

This means the logo is scaled for the secondary tile and looks terrible:

[image: terribly scaled logo]

Is there any way to prevent the logo from being scaled so it looks more like a normal live tile?

[image: nicely scaled logo]

I've tried specifying the tile size as `TileSize.Square71x71` in the constructor, but this simply throws an exception.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

The exception I get is:

```
{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
Exception = {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}
Message = "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"
```

But I think that makes sense because I think secondary tiles only accept two sizes in the constructor, `TileSize.Square150x150` and `TileSize.Wide310x150`.

---

**Edit 2**

The code that throws the exception is:

```
var secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile("myId",
    "sweet name",
    "sweet args",
    myLogoUri,
    TileSize.Square71x71);
```

If I change the last line to `TileSize.Square150x150);` no exception is thrown, but then I'm left with the larger tile.

Comment: What is the exception message you are getting?

Comment: Also please post the code which throws the exception. Or create a square image with the orange background & place you logo in it's centre without scaling.

Comment: @asitis See edit 2.  Yeah, currently I'm working on placing the logo in a square image.  Was hoping for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going for a work around.

I'm placing the icon on a transparent background which is the right size, thus preventing scaling.

If anyone has cleaner solution I'd be stoked to hear it!